# Enter key doesn't work anymore. What can I do?

Tags: linux, laptop, boot, keyboard

While I was using the computer, the enter key doesn't work anymore on my laptop ( hp nx7300 ).

The problem is that the BIOS has a password so I can't go on ubuntu without writing the password and pushing the enter key.

What can I do ?
Maybe is there a combination keys that works like the enter key ?

This is the keyboard of the laptop:
[image]

Comment: Ctrl-M should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Trying plugging in a usb keyboard, that may solve your issue